# What can kill a Java process on Linux other than OOM?

Tags: java, linux, jvm, out-of-memory

I have two virtual servers for hosting my web app. They are identical, running Debian 6 with 1.5GB of RAM. I configure the OS and Tomcat using a script from a fresh install, so I know they are identical.

My webapp runs in Tomcat and I set 850M heap and 100M perm size. My app regularly dies on one of the servers. My first instinct was to check for the OOM killer, but there is no evidence of this in the logs.

Questions:

- Can the OOM killer kill apps without leaving an appropriate log message?
- [Edit] If no, and given that there is nothing obvious to me that would kill the process, where can I find the evidence to diagnose the problem?

Thanks

Comment: Just about anything running as the user who owns the process or as the superuser can kill it.  So the question shouldn't be "What can?" but rather "what would?"  Are you sure the process isn't dying/crashing by itself?

Comment: Are the two servers using the same virtualization technology? I recall old versions of OpenVZ had issues with java applications..

Comment: Well, even a `System.exit(0)` in your webApp can stop the Java Process. Of course it also depends on the configuration of the Logger and the exception handling of the Application if you will see a "appropriate log message" if things go wrong.

Comment: @ChrisStratton, Matthias - Sorry, I realise that in principle anything can kill the process. I will rephrase my question... There is nothing obvious to me that is killing it would do this. I guess my question should be - Given that I have no idea why my app is dying on one vps but not another, where can I find the best evidence of what killed it?

Comment: @Nelson - they are both hosted by budgetvm.com (although in different locations) and I believe the technology is OpenVZ VPS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reasons for a JVM to be terminated are plentiful. It can terminate based on **signals** the owning user or root sends to it, it can also terminate based on the **OOM killer** (like you mentioned).

In several instances, I could trace random crashes back to **bad/faulty RAM**, which lead to memory corruption in the JVM, which in the end lead to the process terminating with `SIGSEGV`. You could look if there are `hs_err_pidXXXX.log` files. They might be missing if the user running the process doesn't have permissions to write in the target directory. You can specify where they go using `-XX:ErrorFile=/path/to/file.`

Due to personal experience, in case of sporadic, untracable, unexplainable random crashes, the first thing I normally do is running `memtest86` for a few hours. I tend to have a PXE bootable image of it in the network.

EDIT: Given that you are mentioning a virtual private server operated by another company, running memtest86 on the bare metal won't be possible for you, but there is a user-space versions as well that might be worth trying.

Comment: This is a good answer to my general question. In my specific case, I think the issue was OpenVZ not being giving me the memory I need, although I never found any logs to confirm.

Answer (score 0):

if you want the JVM to be killed on OOM(which is a valid use case sometimes), you can start the JVM with following option: `-XX:OnOutOfMemoryError=kill -9 %p`